# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 CHECK constraint failed:

Tags: php, sql, laravel, sqlite, eloquent

am using laravel 7.2 for a project am working on and for some reasons, i have decided to use an sqlite database which is not bad anyway but the things is, i don't know much about slite databases. plus everything has been fine until `Integrity constraint violation: 19 CHECK constraint failed:` error came up.
Well, i thought it was my code **"which of-course could still be"** causing the error, until i tried inserting data manually into the database table and i got [image]

**I tried inserting data from my controller**

```php
Merge::create([
       'user_id' => $query->user_id,
       'merge_id' => $to_be_merged->id,
       'investment_id' => $query->id,
       'file' => null,
       'merge_status' => 'pending',
       'merged_user_action' => 'pending',
       'merge_expiry' => Carbon::now()->addDay()
   ]);
```

**And that lead to this error**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 CHECK constraint failed: cashflow_merges (SQL: insert into "cashflow_merges" ("user_id", "merge_id", "investment_id", "file", "merge_status", "merged_user_action", "merge_expiry", "updated_at", "created_at") values (21, 47, 7, ?, pending, pending, 2020-09-10 16:23:41, 2020-09-09 16:23:41, 2020-09-09 16:23:41))
```

And there, the **CHECK** constraint error again. still trying to figure out what that means.

**The migration**

```php
 Schema::create('cashflow_merges', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
     $table->integer('merge_id')->unsigned();
     $table->integer('investment_id')->unsigned();
     $table->string('file')->nullable();
     $table->enum('merge_status', ['pending', 'denied', 'complete', 'canceled', 'expired']);
     $table->enum('merged_user_action', ['waiting', 'seen', 'expired']);
     $table->string('merge_expiry');
     $table->timestamps();
  });
```

Comment: Not sure, but may be this is the error `'file' => null,` give a value and try again

Comment: @sta i have done that, still the same, besides, file is nullable

Comment: Did you add `file` on model's $fillable property?

Comment: @sta protected $guarded = [] i guess

Comment: ok i just got an error: says database is locked

Comment: Field 'merged_user_action' can be only ['waiting', 'seen', 'expired'], but you provide 'pending'

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev i wonder why i didn't see that. that totally solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your migration, the `merged_user_action` field does not have `pending` enum but you are inserting `pending` through your `create statement`. You need to use a value from defined enum values only.

Comment: pending is not in the migration but i added it later but problem persists. i had to switch to mysql and made the same changes and everything was ok!